# how to limit number of connections on nginx

Tags: nginx, dos, ddos

Recently I have been working on DOS Attacks prevention mechanisms on server . Currently I am using fail2ban mechanism but intially it requires to limit the No. of connections on nginx. Seeking suggestions on how to achieve it.

Comment: Add more details to your question.. how have you been implementing `fail2ban` etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I presume you want http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html . It is probably better doing it at a Linux/Network level however as an attack will still use your servers resources for connections, etc.